# Space is appearing in https url in linux

Tags: linux, shell, curl, command-line-interface, centos6

I am writing a .sh file in centos. In script, am writing curl commamd as

```
curl -u admin:final https://$nodeip:8089/services/cluster/config/config
```

But in CLI it s passing as

```
curl -u admin:final https:// MYHOST:8089/services/cluster/config/config
```

**nodeip** i.e. **MYHOST** value, am fetching from database and passing it into url in same script. as

```
nodeip=`cat $root/dbtmpdn | sed -n '3p'`
```

echo $nodeip shows no space.

When echo *nodeip*, there it shows no space but somehow this space is coming in url.
so how to remove this space in url.

Comment: Try exporting nodeip again... export nodeip=MYHOST... Then an echo https://$nodeip:8089/services/cluster/config/config should show you the correct value

Comment: try to pass variable with quote: "$nodeip"

Comment: @YSU please explain your comment, how to do it.

Comment: confirm your debugging with `echo X"$nodeip"Y` . I bet you see a space in between `X MYHOSTY.` if yes, then just ad another sub cmd to your sed, i.e. `sed -n '3{s/^  *//;p;}'`  Good luck.

Comment: @imp, not sure what was unclear. Your nodeip has a space which is probably not visible. shelter has suggested a way for you to see the space by prefixing an 'X'. You can use the 'export' command I mentioned above to set the value of nodeip to the correct value.

Comment: @shelter yes space is there. sed -n '3{s/^ *//;p;}' how to associate nodeip with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in comments, you can replace your current code

```
nodeip=`cat $root/dbtmpdn | sed -n '3p'`
```

with

```
nodeip=`cat $root/dbtmpdn | sed -n '3{s/^ *//;p;}'`
```

Or if `$root/dbtmpdn` is a file, you can simplify with

```
nodeip=`sed -n '3{s/^ *//;p;}' $root/dbtmpdn`
```

AND if your shell will support it, use the "modern" version of command-substitution. (I believe I have read that the default shell in centos doesn't support `$(cmd_substituion)`, so if it doesn't work, stick with your `cmd sub`.)

```
nodeip=$(sed -n '3{s/^ *//;p;}' $root/dbtmpdn)
```

In either case, hopefully now

```
echo X"$nodeip"Y
```

will show the space has be deleted by the sed `s/  *//` command.

If not, then please edit your question to include the output of

```
echo "X" `sed -n '3{p;q;}`  $root/dbtmpdn`
```

Comment: @shelter Thanks a lot shelter. indexernodeip=`echo $indexernodeip | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *$//g'` I used, it is also working.

Comment: @imp. Sorry I missed this before. But, but, but! you're running extra processes when you don't need to.You can have both substitions run  by 1 sed cmd. i.e. `.... | sed 's/^ *//g;s/*$//g'` (I can't make out what is going on in your 2nd sed. Just connect the two substitions with a `;` char. Right now it probably doesn't matter, but form good habits for when your processing those terabyte files! Good luck.